# *** glibc detected *** /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby: corrupted double-linked list: 0xb5a40260 ***

Tags: ruby-on-rails, glibc

9.2 and rails 3.0.1 and I have error that happens to me often and I don't know from where to start debugging.After the error rails server dies. Thanks in advance to anyone that can help me. Here is the stack trace:

```
*** glibc detected *** /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby: corrupted double-linked list: 0xb5a40260 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x73e42)[0xb742fe42]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x741b8)[0xb74301b8]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x74a9d)[0xb7430a9d]
/home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(ruby_xfree+0x1f)[0xb75e1d9f]
/home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x12c3bf)[0xb76a13bf]
/home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x6b4ed)[0xb75e04ed]
/home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_gc_finalize_deferred+0x39)[0xb75e41c9]
/home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x17c611)[0xb76f1611]
/home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x1716c9)[0xb76e66c9]
/home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x167f10)[0xb76dcf10]
/home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x16d4d0)[0xb76e24d0]
/home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x16ea5a)[0xb76e3a5a]
/home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x16f203)[0xb76e4203]
/home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x1713bf)[0xb76e63bf]
/home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x167f10)[0xb76dcf10]
/home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x16d4d0)[0xb76e24d0]
/home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_vm_invoke_proc+0xf9)[0xb76e34c9]
/home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x17ced9)[0xb76f1ed9]
/home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(+0x17cfe7)[0xb76f1fe7]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x6d4c)[0xb73a6d4c]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x5e)[0xb74a6ace]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-08049000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2888317    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
08049000-0804a000 r--p 00000000 08:01 2888317    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
0804a000-0804b000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 2888317    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
0918c000-0bc24000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b4100000-b4231000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b4231000-b4300000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b4300000-b4400000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b4486000-b4800000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b4800000-b4a00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b4a00000-b4c00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b4c00000-b4e00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b4e00000-b4e21000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b4e21000-b4f00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b4f7f000-b4f80000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b4f80000-b5000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b5000000-b5021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b5021000-b5100000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b517d000-b51fe000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b51fe000-b51ff000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b51ff000-b5300000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b5300000-b5321000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b5321000-b5400000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b547f000-b5480000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b5480000-b5500000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b5500000-b5521000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b5521000-b5600000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b567d000-b56fe000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b56fe000-b56ff000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b56ff000-b5800000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b5800000-b5821000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b5821000-b5900000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b597f000-b5980000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b5980000-b5a00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b5a00000-b5af3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b5af3000-b5b00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b5b63000-b5b77000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4327144    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/enc/trans/single_byte.so
b5b77000-b5b7a000 r--p 00013000 08:01 4327144    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/enc/trans/single_byte.so
b5b7a000-b5b7b000 rw-p 00016000 08:01 4327144    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/enc/trans/single_byte.so
b5b7b000-b5bfc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b5bfc000-b5bfd000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b5bfd000-b5cfe000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b5cfe000-b5cff000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b5cff000-b5e00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b5e00000-b5f00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b5f00000-b5f28000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 7079939    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/libxml-ruby-2.3.3/lib/libxml_ruby.so
b5f28000-b5f29000 r--p 00027000 08:01 7079939    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/libxml-ruby-2.3.3/lib/libxml_ruby.so
b5f29000-b5f2a000 rw-p 00028000 08:01 7079939    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/libxml-ruby-2.3.3/lib/libxml_ruby.so
b5f2a000-b5f2b000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b5f2b000-b672b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b672b000-b67ad000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 19665143   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.11.7.0
b67ad000-b67ae000 r--p 00081000 08:01 19665143   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.11.7.0
b67ae000-b67b0000 rw-p 00082000 08:01 19665143   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.11.7.0
b67b0000-b68f7000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10225514   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.7.8
b68f7000-b68fb000 r--p 00147000 08:01 10225514   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.7.8
b68fb000-b68fc000 rw-p 0014b000 08:01 10225514   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.7.8
b68fc000-b68fd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b68fd000-b6937000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10225519   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxslt.so.1.1.26
b6937000-b6938000 r--p 00039000 08:01 10225519   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxslt.so.1.1.26
b6938000-b6939000 rw-p 0003a000 08:01 10225519   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxslt.so.1.1.26
b6939000-b694c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10225520   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexslt.so.0.8.15
b694c000-b694d000 r--p 00012000 08:01 10225520   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexslt.so.0.8.15
b694d000-b694e000 rw-p 00013000 08:01 10225520   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexslt.so.0.8.15
b6962000-b697b000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 6554470    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/nokogiri-1.5.5/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.so
b697b000-b697c000 r--p 00018000 08:01 6554470    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/nokogiri-1.5.5/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.so
b697c000-b697d000 rw-p 00019000 08:01 6554470    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/nokogiri-1.5.5/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.so
b697d000-b6999000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 19661748   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b6999000-b699a000 r--p 0001b000 08:01 19661748   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b699a000-b699b000 rw-p 0001c000 08:01 19661748   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b699b000-b6c38000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10227962   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0
b6c38000-b6c3b000 r--p 0029d000 08:01 10227962   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0
b6c3b000-b6cb1000 rw-p 002a0000 08:01 10227962   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0
b6cb1000-b6cb4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6cb4000-b6cb7000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 19661754   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0.8.0
b6cb7000-b6cb8000 r--p 00002000 08:01 19661754   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0.8.0
b6cb8000-b6cb9000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 19661754   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0.8.0
b6cb9000-b6cbf000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 6950172    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/lib/bcrypt_ext.so
b6cbf000-b6cc0000 r--p 00005000 08:01 6950172    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/lib/bcrypt_ext.so
b6cc0000-b6cc2000 rw-p 00006000 08:01 6950172    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/lib/bcrypt_ext.so
b6cc2000-b6cc6000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4985635    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/racc/cparse.so
b6cc6000-b6cc7000 r--p 00003000 08:01 4985635    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/racc/cparse.so
b6cc7000-b6cc8000 rw-p 00004000 08:01 4985635    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/racc/cparse.so
b6cc8000-b6cdf000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 6687324    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mysql-2.8.1/lib/mysql_api.so
b6cdf000-b6ce0000 r--p 00016000 08:01 6687324    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mysql-2.8.1/lib/mysql_api.so
b6ce0000-b6ce1000 rw-p 00017000 08:01 6687324    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mysql-2.8.1/lib/mysql_api.so
b6ce1000-b6d07000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3412490    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/socket.so
b6d07000-b6d08000 r--p 00025000 08:01 3412490    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/socket.so
b6d08000-b6d09000 rw-p 00026000 08:01 3412490    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/socket.so
b6d09000-b6d58000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 19666850   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
b6d58000-b6d59000 ---p 0004f000 08:01 19666850   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
b6d59000-b6d5b000 r--p 0004f000 08:01 19666850   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
b6d5b000-b6d5f000 rw-p 00051000 08:01 19666850   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
b6d5f000-b6dab000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3412485    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/openssl.so
b6dab000-b6dac000 r--p 0004c000 08:01 3412485    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/openssl.so
b6dac000-b6dad000 rw-p 0004d000 08:01 3412485    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/openssl.so
b6dad000-b6dae000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6dae000-b6e50000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 10223874   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
b6e50000-b6e51000 r--p 000a2000 08:01 10223874   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
b6e51000-b6e52000 rw-p 000a3000 08:01 10223874   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
b6e52000-b6e53000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6e57000-b6e62000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 19661778   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.15.so
b6e62000-b6e63000 r--p 0000a000 08:01 19661778   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.15.so
b6e63000-b6e64000 rw-p 0000b000 08:01 19661778   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.15.so
b6e64000-b6e65000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3412468    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/fcntl.so
b6e65000-b6e66000 r--p 00000000 08:01 3412468    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/fcntl.so
b6e66000-b6e67000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 3412468    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/fcntl.so
b6e67000-b6e6f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 6688020    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.so
b6e6f000-b6e70000 r--p 00007000 08:01 6688020    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.so
b6e70000-b6e71000 rw-p 00008000 08:01 6688020    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.so
b6e71000-b6e78000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 7345360    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/json-1.7.4/lib/json/ext/generator.so
b6e78000-b6e79000 r--p 00007000 08:01 7345360    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/json-1.7.4/lib/json/ext/generator.so
b6e79000-b6e7a000 rw-p 00008000 08:01 7345360    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/json-1.7.4/lib/json/ext/generator.so
b6e7a000-b6e7b000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4199329    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/enc/utf_32le.so
b6e7b000-b6e7c000 r--p 00000000 08:01 4199329    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/enc/utf_32le.so
b6e7c000-b6e7d000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 4199329    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/enc/utf_32le.so
b6e7d000-b6e7e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4199333    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/enc/utf_32be.so
b6e7e000-b6e7f000 r--p 00000000 08:01 4199333    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/enc/utf_32be.so
b6e7f000-b6e80000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 4199333    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/enc/utf_32be.so
b6e80000-b6e81000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4199360    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/enc/utf_16le.so
b6e81000-b6e82000 r--p 00000000 08:01 4199360    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/enc/utf_16le.so
b6e82000-b6e83000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 4199360    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/enc/utf_16le.so
b6e83000-b6e84000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4199354    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/enc/utf_16be.so
b6e84000-b6e85000 r--p 00000000 08:01 4199354    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/enc/utf_16be.so
b6e85000-b6e86000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 4199354    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/enc/utf_16be.so
b6e86000-b6e94000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3412474    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/bigdecimal.so
b6e94000-b6e95000 r--p 0000d000 08:01 3412474    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/bigdecimal.so
b6e95000-b6e96000 rw-p 0000e000 08:01 3412474    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/bigdecimal.so
b6e96000-b6ea3000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3412478    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/zlib.so
b6ea3000-b6ea4000 r--p 0000c000 08:01 3412478    /home/tsvetelina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/zlib.soAborted (core dumped)
```

UPDATE:
Now the error happened on dev too. In the app there is image caching. And the error leads to one method:

```
def f_respond_to (merge_result,fieldable)
  respond_to do |format|
        format.html
  format.png do
            i = ImageCaching.new
            updated_at = get_updated_at(fieldable)
            att = i.find_or_destroy_by_uri(request.path,updated_at)
            if(att == nil)
                att = create_new_image(i, merge_result)
            end
            render :text=>i.read(att.uri), :content_type=>att.content_type
  end
  format.pdf do
            redirect_to download_pdf_path(:key=>fieldable.key)
  end
    end
end
```

Comment: looks to be a bug in 1.9.2 .  Check out bug #4009.  seems like it could be what you are hitting? http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/353195  Have you tried it on 1.9.3?

Comment: Thanks for answering I install 1.9.3 and I will try it

Comment: I tried 1.9.3-p194 but I still get the error. I should mention that the error happens in production env. In development is ok

Comment: do you use different gems/versions/operating systems between dev and prod?

Comment: no. I only use different databases. On dev I am with sqlite3 and on prod I am with mysql

Comment: I just got a similar error today, though the memory addresses are different.

Comment: Allex D what is happening now? Does the error still occurs?